# Interpretation of directedness in ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test, interpretation

As far as I know, ANOVA results can be interpreted with respect to mean differences between 2 or more groups. But, we can not make any inference on which mean is *larger* or *smaller* in a statistically significant way based on an ANOVA.

However, I have recently read a study ([article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29334233)) where
a significant p-value together with absolute mean differences was interpreted with respect to directionality ("While the more educated respondents experienced significantly **more**
lifetime discrimination (F = 2.68, p <.05)").

This, without an additional one-sided t-test or such being performed.
Is this a correct way of statistically interpreting an ANOVA?

**Article:** Yoon et al. (2019): Perceived discrimination and mental health among older African Americans: the role of psychological well-being

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post with a full citation for the article, not just the link, as links can die. Thanks!